# What kind of transformation is applied in the demo apps in on mesh files CGAL?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I have a mesh, which is shown below, that I want to use for path planning. I am following this tutorial for that. https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/index.html

[image]

When I use the provided demo and calculate the path between two vertices, its demo console shows selected vertices as

```
 [11:56:42] INFO: Shortest Paths: Selected Face: 5428; Barycentric coordinates: 0.0669871 0.0131695 0.919843

 [11:56:49] INFO: Shortest Paths: Selected Face: 4813; Barycentric coordinates: 0.00400777 0.983581 0.0124108
```

However, vertices in the mesh file are not in this range, for example, {334746, 1165, 66225}, i.e., **values of vertices are really large**.

**Question: In the demo app, what kind of transformation is applied to the input mesh file?**

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>

#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_shortest_path.h>

#include <CGAL/AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel             Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                                 Point_3;
typedef Kernel::Ray_3                                                   Ray_3;

typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3>                                     Triangle_mesh;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path_traits<Kernel, Triangle_mesh>  Traits;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path<Traits>                        Surface_mesh_shortest_path;

typedef boost::graph_traits<Triangle_mesh>                              Graph_traits;
typedef Graph_traits::vertex_iterator                                   vertex_iterator;
typedef Graph_traits::face_iterator                                     face_iterator;

typedef typename Surface_mesh_shortest_path::Barycentric_coordinates    Barycentric_coordinates;
typedef typename Surface_mesh_shortest_path::Face_location              Face_location;

typedef CGAL::AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive<Triangle_mesh>         AABB_face_graph_primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<Kernel, AABB_face_graph_primitive>            AABB_face_graph_traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<AABB_face_graph_traits>                         AABB_tree;

typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3> Mesh;
typedef Mesh::Vertex_index vertex_descriptor;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const std::string filename = (argc>1) ? argv[1] : CGAL::data_file_path("meshes/elephant.off");

  Triangle_mesh tmesh;
  if(!CGAL::IO::read_polygon_mesh(filename, tmesh) ||
     !CGAL::is_triangle_mesh(tmesh))
  {
    std::cerr << "Invalid input file." << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // or the C++11 for loop. Note that there is a ':' and not a ',' as in BOOST_FOREACH
  for(vertex_descriptor vd : tmesh.vertices()){
    std::cout << tmesh.point(vd) << std::endl;
  }

  Surface_mesh_shortest_path shortest_paths(tmesh);
  const Point_3 source_pt(334746, 1165, 66225);
  Face_location source_loc = shortest_paths.locate<AABB_face_graph_traits>(source_pt); // this builds an AABB tree of the mesh
  shortest_paths.add_source_point(source_loc.first, source_loc.second);
  AABB_tree tree;
  shortest_paths.build_aabb_tree(tree);

  const Point_3 target_pt(370364, 809, 66265.6);
  Face_location target_loc = shortest_paths.locate<AABB_face_graph_traits>(target_pt);

  std::vector<Point_3> points;
  shortest_paths.shortest_path_points_to_source_points(target_loc.first, target_loc.second, std::back_inserter(points));

  // Print the points
  std::cout << points.size() << " ";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << " |----| " << points[i] << "\n";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I have no experience with CGAL and I don't know how the shortest path is calculated. But the console output tells you about the [*barycentric* coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of some point on a triangular face. Barycentric coordinates are always local to one triangle (more generally: simplex) and the coordinate values are always between 0 and 1.

Comment: @joergbrech thank you for the information, I will have a look